# Чтение кириллицы из appsettings.json

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

В общем, есть у меня в конфигурации один параметр, который имеет значение в виде кириллицы.

Так вот, если получать значение через `GetSection("Section")["Str"]`, то у меня получаются кракозябры.

Подскажи, а как правильно прочитать строку в правильно из Json'а в файле конфигурации?

Answer (score 1):

json сохранил в `UTF8` и все четко заработало.